# Python: Finding dictionaries in a list that have some keys of another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have two list of dictionaries that are quite long. I want to find dictionaries in second list that have the keys in the first list of dictionaries and separate them based on another key. Some of the keys in the list one are values in the list two.

Here is an example:

```
students = [{'123': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 2}]}, 
            {'124': [{'course1': 3}, {'course2': 4}]}, 
            {'125': [{'course1': 24}, {'course2': 12}]}, 
            {'126': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 24}]}, ...]

finals = [{'student_number':'123', 'exam':'passed',...},
          {'student_number':'124', 'exam':'ungraded',...},
          {'student_number':'125', 'exam':'failed',...}, ...]
```

## Finding student_numbers in finals that exist in students and separate them based on 'exam' key:

```
# Students who passed exam, 'exam' = 'passed'
passed_students = ['123', ...]

# Other Students
other_students = ['124', '125', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure that your data is in the best format, but given what you have the following code will work:

```
students = [{'123': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 2}]},
            {'124': [{'course1': 3}, {'course2': 4}]},
            {'125': [{'course1': 24}, {'course2': 12}]},
            {'126': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 24}]}]

finals = [{'student_number':'123', 'exam':'passed'},
          {'student_number':'124', 'exam':'ungraded'},
          {'student_number':'125', 'exam':'failed'}]

studentIDs = [i.keys()[0] for i in students]

passed_students=[]
other_students=[]
for row in finals:
    snum = row['student_number']
    status = row['exam']
    if status=='passed' and snum in studentIDs:
        passed_students.append(snum)
    elif status!='passed' and snum in studentIDs:
        other_students.append(snum)
    else:
        print 'Student ID {0} not found in list.'.format(snum)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little exercise for list comprehensions:

```
students = [{'123': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 2}]},
            {'124': [{'course1': 3}, {'course2': 4}]},
            {'125': [{'course1': 24}, {'course2': 12}]},
            {'126': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 24}]}]

finals = [{'student_number':'123', 'exam':'passed',},
          {'student_number':'124', 'exam':'ungraded',},
          {'student_number':'125', 'exam':'failed',},]

# Extract student id numbers.
student_ids = set(
    student_data.keys()[0]
    for student_data in students)

# Restrict finals to the students that exist in students.
students_with_finals = [
    final
    for final in finals
    if final['student_number'] in student_ids]

passed_students = [
    final['student_number']
    for final in students_with_finals
    if final['exam'] == 'passed']

other_students = [
    final['student_number']
    for final in students_with_finals
    if final['exam'] != 'passed']

print('Passed students: {}'.format(passed_students))
print('Other students: {}'.format(other_students))
```

Result:

```
Passed students: ['123']
Other students: ['124', '125']
```

It looks like that the data structures could be simplified by using dictionaries with the student ids as keys:

```
students = {
    '123': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 2}],
    '124': [{'course1': 3}, {'course2': 4}],
    '125': [{'course1': 24}, {'course2': 12}],
    '126': [{'course1': 2}, {'course2': 24}],
}

finals = {
    '123': {'exam':'passed', 'points': 100},
    '124': {'exam':'ungraded'},
    '125': {'exam':'failed'},
}
```

Comment: Thanks Helko, your solution is better than what I wrote, 3 nested for loops + 2 nested if.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> students = {'123':{'name':'Bonnie','course_1':2, 'course_2':2},
...             '124':{'name':'Jerry', 'course_1':3, 'course_2':4},
...             '125':{'name':'Bob', 'course_1':24, 'course_2':12},
...             '126':{'name':'Jill', 'course_1':2, 'course_2':24}}
>>> finals = [{'num':'123', 'exam':'passed'},
...           {'num':'124', 'exam':'ungraded'},
...           {'num':'125', 'exam':'failed'}]
>>> student_results = {'passed':[], 'ungraded':[], 'failed':[]}
>>>
>>> for final in finals:
...    student_results[final['exam']].append(students[final['num']])
>>>        
>>> # Print student results.
>>> for result in ['passed', 'ungraded', 'failed']:
...     print "Students %s:" % result
...     for student in student_results[result]:
...         print "   " + student['name']
...
Students passed:
   Bonnie
Students ungraded:
   Jerry
Students failed:
   Bob
```